# FFT is not showing noise

Tags: noise, fft

I have current values and respective time.

[image]

There is noise in the signal. But when I am calculating FFT, it is not showing

[image]

I have recorded the values at every 5ms.

below is my code:

```
time = data['Time'].values
current = data['Current'].values

# 2. FFT Computation
fs = 200  # 5ms sampling interval means a 50 Hz sampling rate
current_fft = np.fft.fft(current)
frequencies = np.fft.fftfreq(len(current), 1/fs)
```

Can someone help me to find the noise?

I am a newbie and please spare me if I am wrong somewhere

Comment: I'm always annoyed that none of these signal processing packages have a built in convenience method mean_subtracted_fft(X) that does fft(X-mean(X)).

Comment: If you zero the first output from the FFT with something like `current_fft[0]=min(current_fft)`, then you will be able to see that your "flat" transformed signal is not that flat.

Answer (score 17):

> it is not showing

That's because you're not using logarithmic scale for the magnitude.

Even without DC removal, a dB-scaled plot of the fft magnitude will show the noise all right.

In most cases, linear-scaled spectrum plots are useless, since a linearly scaled graph has a mediocre dynamic range.

Suppose you got a 300 DPI printer, and the graph is 7in high - say printed in landscape on letter-sized paper. Suppose that the graph line thickness is 1 pixel, or 1/300th of an inch.

The dynamic range of such a linearly scaled plot is
$$
\frac{\frac{1}{300}{\,\rm in}}{7 {\,\rm in}}=5\cdot10^{-4}\approx66{\,\rm dB}.
$$

That is not very much to say the least, and you only can really use this range if you get a printout or are viewing the graph on a 300DPI screen - for example, on a "retina" screen of a tablet. And *even then*, you need to have corrected vision better than 20/20 to actually see the individual pixels and take advantage of this range. In practice, the dynamic range of a single-pixel-wide line plot on a 7" high on a retina tablet screen is around 60 dB.

That thick line plot you have shown has the line about 2 pixels high, and the vertical range is about 220 pixels. That is a *measly* 40dB of dynamic range - less than 7 bits of resolution!

Answer (score 14):

Your signal's measurements are centered around 21.5 or so, and as a result your signal has a large DC offset. In `current_fft`, the AC components are still there, just very small compared to your large spike at/near DC. They should be visible if you plotted your current chart, with the data kept as-is, with the Y axis in logarithmic scale.

If you want to remove the observed DC component from your data, subtract the mean of the data from all of the observations in `current` before taking the Fourier transform. Due to the mathematical properties of FT, this should be the same as zeroing out the bin corresponding to the DC component in `current_fft` and leaving all other bins unchanged.